# How do I block same device registration by their ip address?

Tags: php

I am preparing a registration form for my website where they can register and track how many registered so far. But I encountered some issues that some people register multiple times by using different details from same device. I would like to stop that cheat. Anyone help me to overcome this issue. I want to track their ip or their device details and restrict multiple registration.

Comment: IP address is not sufficient to determine the uniqueness of a user. Imagine someone registering from their school or workplace, where everyone has the same IP. Or I can just use a VPN or a mobile connection to change my IP. Short answer is; you can never be 100% sure.

Comment: You could require a phone number, send a verification code to the number. That should reduce multiple registrations.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the `$_SERVER` array: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

The thing that might interest You most in this case would be `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

Just remember that many PCs from the same network might have the same IP, so You can't just block them purely on the IP. Be careful to not block normal users by accident. You might want to set a cookie as well.

Obviously You won't be able to 100% block multiaccount cheaters if they know what they are doing, but You should be able to either catch most of them, of force them to give up. Add things like not allow to register multiples accounts on the same email, force to solve hard captha, email confirmation links etc. Often it is just a small deal, but it simply makes multiaccount-cheaters life a little harder, and most of them will give up just because of that.

Sometimes is good idea to let them be for some time and log the multiaccounts for some time. Then block them all at once, so they won't know if they managed to bypass Your security or not at the very second when they try to create account.

Check as well other `$_SERVER` variables that You might find useful, like `HTTP_USER_AGENT` that returns very specific information about browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP superglobal $_SERVER to find their ip. Then use some validation on whether to accept the registration.